# OData vs EF Code First Fluent API or both?

Tags: c#, oracle, ef-code-first, odata, ef-fluent-api

I've been assigned to a project which basically replaces an Oracle Forms application. The requirements were pretty straightforward, to create an Intranet ASP.NET MVC application with Oracle as RDBMS, to be consume by customer over desktop browsers. Therefore, I'm free to architect the application utilizing what I consider is better. In the past I would architect the Data Access Layer through a Repository pattern with Entity Framework DataBase First approach. However, I would like to follow a SOA approach considering it provides a loosely-couple design, separation of concerns and so forth. My concern and questions are regarding OData, EF Code First approach and Fluent API. In that, OData provides the data service layer I am looking for. However, some folks have mentioned to consider EF Code First and Fluent API. At this point, after reading some documentation I ended up with more questions than answers.

- Is it one approach better than the other one?
- Could I combine them? If so, how?
- What would be the best practice to implement?

Any help would be really appreciated. It doesn't have to be too detailed but if so, it's fine. Ideas, guidelines, best practices are the type of answers it would really help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are not alternatives. Code first is a workflow where your code models are used to create your database. The fluent api is the method you use to specify relationships and other database configuration (max length, data type overrides, etc). Web API then contains your EF or repository code. OData is a layer that sits on top of web api. See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Comment: Thanks Steve. I guess Fluent API provides robustness to data annotations then.

Comment: Fluent API is an alternative to annotations and conventions. I prefer fluent because it separates concerns keeps my models POCO. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

Comment: Thanks Steve. I want to mark down this question as answered but I cannot. I guess it is because your answers set as comments.

Comment: No worries. Good luck.